# How to access( set or get or bind ) controls in rad grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, telerik, radgrid

This is the first time i use The [RadGrid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/edit-form-types/defaultcs.aspx)

---

```
 <telerik:radgrid id="gv_about" runat="server" cssclass="RadGrid" allowpaging="True"
            pagesize="20" allowsorting="True" autogeneratecolumns="False" showstatusbar="True"
            allowautomaticdeletes="True" allowautomaticinserts="True" allowautomaticupdates="True"
            datasourceid="ObjectDataSource1" onitemdeleted="gv_about_ItemDeleted" oniteminserted="gv_about_ItemInserted"
            onitemupdated="gv_about_ItemUpdated" onitemcommand="gv_about_ItemCommand" onprerender="gv_about_PreRender">
        <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
            <commanditemsettings addnewrecordtext="&#1575;&#1590;&#1575;&#1601;&#1577;" showrefreshbutton="False" />
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="emp_num" HeaderText="&#1585;&#1602;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1581;&#1575;&#1590;&#1585;" DataField="emp_num">
                    <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Silver" Width="25px"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Gray"></ItemStyle>
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="name" HeaderText="&#1575;&#1604;&#1575;&#1587;&#1605;" DataField="name">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="220px"></HeaderStyle>
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="degree_name" HeaderText="&#1575;&#1604;&#1583;&#1585;&#1580;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1604;&#1605;&#1610;&#1577;" DataField="degree_name">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="college" HeaderText="&#1575;&#1604;&#1603;&#1604;&#1610;&#1577; &#1608;&#1575;&#1604;&#1580;&#1575;&#1605;&#1593;&#1577;" DataField="college">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="type" HeaderText="&#1606;&#1608;&#1593; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1581;&#1575;&#1590;&#1585;" DataField="type">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="&#1581;&#1584;&#1601;" UniqueName="column">
                </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
<EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1" FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn1 column"></EditColumn>
                <FormTemplate>
                    <table id="Table2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="0" rules="none"
                        style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <tr class="EditFormHeader">
                            <td colspan="2" style="font-size: small">
                                <b>&#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1605;&#1575;&#1585;&#1577; &#1578;&#1593;&#1575;&#1585;&#1601;</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table id="Table3" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="250" border="0" class="module">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                     </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &#1606;&#1608;&#1593; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1581;&#1575;&#1590;&#1585;:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        <div id="div_lect_type">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbt_lect_type" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbt_lect_type_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="&#1605;&#1593;&#1610;&#1606;" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="&#1605;&#1606;&#1578;&#1583;&#1576; &#1582;&#1575;&#1585;&#1580;&#1610;"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="&#1580;&#1583;&#1610;&#1583;"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
    <div id="div_lect">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_lect_in" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txt_lect_in_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txt_lect_in_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters=""
            Enabled="True" MinimumPrefixLength="4" ServiceMethod="Get_Emp_AutoComplete" ServicePath="~/LectIn.asmx"
            TargetControlID="txt_lect_in" BehaviorID="ACE_txt_lect_in" CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
            CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem" CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"
            EnableCaching="False">
        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            City:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                           <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' TabIndex="1">
                                            </asp:TextBox>--%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Region:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                           <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Region") %>' TabIndex="2">
                                            </asp:TextBox>--%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Home Phone:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          <%--  <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="HomePhoneBox" runat="server" SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll"
                                                Text='<%# Bind("HomePhone") %>' PromptChar="_" Width="300px" Mask="(###) ###-####"
                                                TabIndex="3">
                                            </telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>--%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Birth Date:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Title Of Courtesy
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table id="Table1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="250" border="0" class="module">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Notes:
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Address:
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "Insert" : "Update" %>'
                                    runat="server" CommandName='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "PerformInsert" : "Update" %>'>
                                </asp:Button>&nbsp;
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                    CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </FormTemplate>
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick"></ClientEvents>
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:radgrid>
```

---

The main problem is how to access controls in this grid from code behind and how to bind some of them or handling the events of them ??

For example how to access the `txt_lect_in` from code behind ?

Comment: Your txt_lect_in does not have a column associated. Why do you need to access it? Your question is very  general you can find many examples in the Telerik forum http://www.telerik.com/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid otherwise try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditFormItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditFormItem item = e.Item as GridEditFormItem;
        TextBox txt_lect_in = item.FindControl("txt_lect_in") as TextBox;
        //Access your textbox heer
    }
}
//OR
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditFormItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditFormItem item = e.Item as GridEditFormItem;
        TextBox txt_lect_in = item.FindControl("txt_lect_in") as TextBox;
        //Access your textbox heer
    }
}
```